# Is there a way to give Google storage to another user as a gift?

Tags: google, online-storage

Google [offers additional storage](https://www.google.com/accounts/PurchaseStorage) for its services (currently Gmail, Picasa Web, Google Docs). Is there a way to give this to another user as a gift?

I.e. I'd like to pay for it for a year, enter the Gmail address and the other user should be notified about it and get it on his account.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to be logged into the account you are purchasing storage for;

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1047457

> The extra storage is only available to you. You can't share it with other users or transfer it to another account. **You can't purchase storage for other users**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I remember reading these first two sentences but missed the third… Not what I wanted to hear, but thanks. Too bad. :(

Comment: It's a shame Google don't offer this in the same way that Flickr can offer gift Pro accounts - http://www.flickr.com/gift/